# benefits of learning python network programming?

Tags: python, network-programming

I was looking at a book on python network programming and i wanted to know what would be the benefits to learning python network programming comprehensively? This would be in the context of being able to develop some really cool, ground breaking web apps. I am a python newbe so all opinions woul be appreciated.

Kind Regards

4 Years later:
This was 4yrs ago, its crazy how much I've grown as a developer. Regarding how it has helped,  I've developed an email application, a chat application using Objective C, python Twisted on the server side, it also helped with developing my apns push notification pipeline.

Comment: Network programming != web applications.

Comment: Newbie != cool, ground breaking apps.

Comment: newbee does not mean asking-clear-questions. what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is email, yahoo messenger, streaming of files not an example of using networking technology? The reason why i ask is because these tpoics are covered in the python network programming book. I don't have a specific project in mind, i am just contemplating whether it will add anything to my ability to build web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Network programming" isn't about "cool web apps". It's more about creating servers, and creating clients that talk to servers. It's about sockets, tcp/ip communication, XMLRPC, http protocols and all the technologies that let two computers talk to each other.

If all you're interested in is web apps, learning network programming won't benefit you a whole lot.

Comment: I am basically interested in knowing if i will get any synergy from  knowing web devlopment and network programming and how well can it be combined to develop something cool.

Comment: You dont need to know how to design a drivetrain or the top/bottom end of an engine to slap a car together that would get you from point a to point b. But if you did, you'd be able to build it way more efficient and/or squeeze better times off a quarter mile.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop wed apps, than you should rather focus on web frameworks like `Django` or `Pylons`.

Comment: I already use web2py, but i was just wondering wether going through a book on python network programming would be of any benefit as it does cover web programming and sockets, transfering files etc....

Comment: If you want to make cool web apps, then I think it's better to learn something about front end - maybe `jQuery` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

"python network programming" isn't any special kind of network programming. It sounds like if you had a better grasp on network programming you would be able to see where python would fit in to your overall design. And instead of reading a generic book about it, you would dig through the python API's and go from there.

The cool thing about python is that it's a huge collection of libraries which are optimized to  each task. At work we use python to do all our server-side heavy lifting. We then use jquery and the Objective-J based Cappuccino to present an interface to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The network is and always will be the sexiest arena for a hacker. An attacker can do almost anything with simple network access, such as scan for hosts, inject packets, sniff data, remotely exploit hosts, and much more. But if you are an attacker who has worked your way into the deepest depths of an enterprise target, you may find yourself in a bit of a conundrum: you have no tools to execute network attacks. No netcat. No Wireshark. No compiler and no means to install one. However, you might be surprised to find that in many cases, you’ll find a Python install.
Hence, the one benefit of python network programming I see is that one has a chance of becoming a penetration tester or an Offensive security guy.

Edit (10-06-2020):
I have no knowledge of what I was thinking when I was writing this answer. It's clearly not helpful. 
Regarding the question, making web apps is not equivalent to network programming. In network programming with python, you can start with lower level of the OSI model by using libraries like scapy. Here you can make raw packets and understand the various protocols with it. And then maybe move to application level with libraries like Scrapy which involves web scraping, making http requests, etc. But develping python web apps would use tools like flask, django, jinja, etc and the development of a web app can take the form totally different than that of a regular scripting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Python's stronger web tool is definitely Django.
Said that the biggest benefit of learning it is to achieve a pretty robust backend on your web project.